# Wordpress sub menu on mobile devices?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, submenu, file-location

I am having problems with my WordPress sub-menu, on a desktop computer it appears fine but on a mobile device it does not show? Is their anyway I can change this?

Also what file does the navigation code sit within? Hopefully I can have a look for myself and see if I can change some code to get it to show on mobile devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's your theme ?

Some doc for Wordpress menu: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: The theme is uploader

Comment: I don't have the code but if it the same I look, you have just to modify the media queries in menu.css and disable main links in js or html.